# Need guidance or tutorials to use gridview

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, visual-studio-2008, grid

Need guidance using gridview which clearly explains:

- how to use gridview programmatically.
- the dataset binding etc with respect to gridview

The source of data is SQL C# statement, like sql command="select etc"

I am using VS08, C# and SQL gridview control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [A Beginner's Guide to the GridView](http://www.aspnet101.com/2007/11/a-beginners-guide-to-the-gridview/)
- [Quickstart Tutorial Gridview](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/gridview.aspx)
- [Using the New GridView Control in ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/22141)

Or just [Google](http://tinyurl.com/265uunk) or [Bing](http://tinyurl.com/28lzez3) for "gridview tutorial" - you'll get **loads** of links.......

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at these tutorials: http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials.

Grz, Kris.